# Como criar UISegmentedControl customizadas?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Como criar `UISegmentedControl` customizadas? Meu objetivo é criar uma `UISegmentedControl` , assim como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dê uma olhada nestes dois tutoriais.

Este: http://www.makemegeek.com/uisegmentedcontrol-example-ios/ e este : 

http://redartisan.com/2010/6/27/uisegmented-control-view-switching-revisited

Comment: o segundo link da Redartisan não é muito claro, ja tinha visto. Tanto que se vc baixar o projeto de exemplo, as explicações no tutorial nem chegam a metade do que foi necessário pra criar o projeto de exemplo.

Comment: O primeiro da makemegeek é mais completo, tem imagens que acompanham quase todo o procedimento de implementação.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse, procure fazer as coisas mais nativamente possível, pois em updates de sistema, ainda vai garantir funcionamento. http://smnh.me/customizing-appearance-of-uisegmentedcontrol/ Tem esse componente pronto também:
https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl

Comment: Obrigado @Diego Dias, Vou estar verificando e retorno com o resultado!